# After installation, pages do not use any CSS style

Tags: installation

I installed Drupal on Ubuntu 22.24. I'm able to get everything done, but after the installation, the next page is all messed up and I have no other permission besides looking at this page.

[image: screenshot]

How can I fix this issue?

I ran `chown -R www-data: /var/www/html/` and `chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/`; if I messed something up with permissions that'll be great!

[image]

This is the error I'm getting from the f12 in the browser.

Comment: Do please check all the system requirements for Drupal. It’s probably missing mod_rewrite. Also be aware that Drupal 9 is end-of-life and unsupported.

Comment: I did do a2enmod rewrite and a2ensite drupal.conf and it still isn't working.

Comment: What are the browser console errors?

Comment: The browser says failed to load resources: the server responded with a status of 404 (not found) then a CSS file.

Comment: So I figured out I guess none of the css files downloaded in the first place as well as the js files. Was I supposed to download those by itself? I was following a video and didn't mention anything about that.

Comment: Would you care to add those 404 logs to the question so that the experts that are here could form an answer? It’s likely you haven’t set up the platform per the requirements.

Comment: What does the system status report on the Reports menu say?

Comment: The report menu in the browser doesn't work I'll just get a 404 page when I try to go to the report page.

Comment: Use a Docker based solution.

Comment: Do please check all the system requirements for Drupal. It’s probably missing mod_rewrite, or mod_rewrite is not actually running. I don’t understand how you managed to install Drupal on that platform. It isn’t set up for Drupal.

Comment: what do you mean it isn't set up for Drupal?

Comment: Drupal is not working because one or more of the system requirements are unmet. https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/system-requirements

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to set write access (recursively) for the following directories:

```
/sites/default/files
```

OR

```
/sites/default/files/js
/sites/default/files/css
/sites/default/files/php
```